# jQuery not updating the DOM element HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a up/down vote system, but when I get the response from the API, I can't seem to target the element I want, which is the span within li with a class of "score".

My js handlers

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function vote(obj, post_id,vote) {
        if(vote && post_id) {

             $.get('/ajax/vote', { 
                v: vote,
                p: post_id
                }, function(data){
                    //set the .score to the new count returned by API
                    console.log(data);
                    $(obj).child('li.score').html(data.votes);
             });
        }
    }
    $(document.body).on("click", ".upvote", function(obj){ 
        console.log("Up Voted");

        var post_id = $(this).closest(".card").prop('id').replace(/post-id-/, '');
        vote(obj,post_id,1); 
    });

    $(document.body).on("click", ".downvote", function(){
        console.log("Down Voted");
        // more to come
    });
});
```

The html view that is trigging the event, and the "score" area that's under it.

```
        <div class="vote-controls col-xs-1">
        <ul>
            <li class="upvote"><a href="#" class="disable"><span class="fa fa-angle-up "></span><span class="sr-only">&uarr;</span></a></li>
            <li class="downvote"><a href="#" class="disable"><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span><span class="sr-only">&darr;</span></a></li>
            <li class="score"><span>0</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This looks like jquery with angular, there may be some special handling required to make your jquery work.

Comment: I dont see any element with `.card` class on it

Comment: That's only on server side load. I'll edit it out for this example. When the template is compiled it has the count on it, when you hit the vote up/down it hits the ajax api and updates the span with the new count.

Comment: Isn't `obj` actually the `Event` object? Not the clicked element?\

Comment: Its in the parent, that part works. its the $(obj).child('li.score').html(data.votes); within the vote function that is not hitting its target.

Comment: I think that's because `obj` is an `Event` object and thus has no `child()`.

Comment: idk Kevin, that's why I'm asking. how should I reference the clicked so the function will be able to use it?

Comment: check my answer below, getting clicked obj from event object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li.score` is not a child of the `obj`. Given that object is actually the DOM object clicked on by passing `$(this)` to the function then I guess it should be:

```
$(obj).parent('ul').children('li.score').html(data.votes);
```

Comment: I guess obj is Event obj, try obj.target or currentTarget ? What say?

Comment: @joyBlanks i udpated the answer. Then dont pass the event obj, pass the DOM element referred to by $(this). Get the parent and then the `li` element required

Comment: I used vote(this,post_id,1) to pass the event into the function, and then used your targeting example. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinBoucher it is not .. i tried that in a snippet and it works. Please explain why you think it is

Comment: `obj` is an `Event` object.

Comment: @KevinBoucher and if you read my answer i said he needs to pass a DOM object by sending `$(this)` as `obj`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `obj` is an `Event` object not your HTML element. Also, there is no `child` method. Use `children`:

Change this line:

```
vote(obj, post_id, 1);
```

to:

```
vote($(this).parents('ul'), post_id, 1);
```

This should pass the `ul` to your `vote()` function.

And change:

```
$(obj).child('li.score').html(data.votes);
```

to:

```
$(obj).children('li.score').html(data.votes);
```

Answer (score -1):

The obj is event object, Here is what you want to do

```
$(obj.currentTarget).siblings('li.score').find('>span').text(html.votes);
```